# Send SNMP trap with powershell script

Tags: powershell, snmp, snmp-trap

I'm trying to send SNMP traps with a powershell script (it has to be a powershell script, it will be running on a windows server). I have a test enviroment running that has a trap reciever.

I've been following this tutorial http://www.activexperts.com/network-component/howto/snmpts/powershell10/ but I haven't gotten it to work.

Below is my code, the script is running fine

```
$objSnmpTrapManager = new-object -comobject AxNetwork.DnsServer #create object
# Create a SnmpTrapOut instance
$objSnmpTrapManager = new-object -comobject AxNetwork.SnmpTrapManager
$objSnmpTrap     = new-object -comobject AxNetwork.SnmpTrap
$objSnmpObject   = new-object -comobject AxNetwork.SnmpObject
$objConstants    = new-object -comobject AxNetwork.NwConstants

# Initialize SNMP
$objSnmpTrapManager.Initialize()
$res = "Initialize, result: " + $objSnmpTrapManager.LastError + " (" + $objSnmpTrapManager.GetErrorDescription( $objSnmpTrapManager.LastError ) + ")"
Write-Host $res
If($objSnmpTrapManager.LastError -ne 0 )
{
  exit
}

# Get Host, community name and optionally a MIB file
$strHostName    = "*******"
$strCommunity   = "public"

# Set trap properties
$objSnmpTrap.Clear()
$objSnmpTrap.Host     = $strHostName
$objSnmpTrap.Community = $strCommunity
$objSnmpTrap.Port     = 80 #is this the port that my trap reciever is looking at? or should it be the default 162

# Add first variable to trap
$objSnmpObject.Clear()
$objSnmpObject.OID   = ".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0"
$objSnmpObject.Type  = $objConstants.nwSNMP_TYPE_OCTETSTRING
$objSnmpObject.Value = "test"
$objSnmpTrap.AddObject($objSnmpObject)

# Send the trap.
$objSnmpTrapManager.Send($objSnmpTrap)
$res = "Send, result: " + $objSnmpTrapManager.LastError + " (" + $objSnmpTrapManager.GetErrorDescription($objSnmpTrapManager.LastError) + ")"
Write-Host $res

# Shutdown SNMP
$objSnmpTrapManager.Shutdown()
$res = "Shutdown, result: " + $objSnmpTrapManager.LastError + " (" + $objSnmpTrapManager.GetErrorDescription($objSnmpTrapManager.LastError) + ")"
Write-Host $res
```

Everything says success, I think my problem is defining the location of where to send my traps (if someone could provide an example that would be awesome!)

Does anyone have any help or resources they'd be willing to share?

Thanks!

Comment: We'd be happy to help, but we need more detail than "I haven't gotten it to work." Does the script you linked to run? If not, what is the full error generated when you try to run it?

Comment: Uploaded some code and more clarification! Thanks! (even you need more clarification just let me know!)

Comment: Well, I bet $strHostName should be set to the SNMP manager -- that should be what defines where the trap is sent.

Also, I would leave the port at the default unless you know for a fact that you are using a non-default port for SNMP (very rare, in my experience).

Comment: That's a very complicated way to send a trap, when all you need is to install net-snmp (http://www.net-snmp.org/) and use a one-line `snmptrap` command to send the trap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The port (`$objSnmpTrap.Port`) should be 162, the default SNMP Trap receiver (or *trapsink*) port - unless you've explicitly changed that to port 80 in your test environment:

```
# Get Host, community name and optionally a MIB file
$strHostName    = "receiver.test.environment.example"
$strCommunity   = "public"

# Set trap properties
$objSnmpTrap.Clear()
$objSnmpTrap.Host     = $strHostName
$objSnmpTrap.Community = $strCommunity
$objSnmpTrap.Port = 162
```