# How to send SNMP Traps with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, snmp

Saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29242392/send-snmp-trap-with-powershell-script) question posted on StackOverflow on how to send SNMP Traps, but that question was using a paid module. Is there an existing module in Powershell which I can use to generate SNMP Traps?

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell does not have a built in module or commands for SNMP that I've ever found. That being said there are free alternatives that will allow you to work with SNMP in PowerShell. [#SNMP](http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com/) has a free open source version that you can easily add a reference to with Add-Type and use just like any .Net class. [Net-SNMP](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/) is also open source and allows you to work with snmp via their tools though it's text based output that you would need to parse.